# Name for Product of Three Cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a number made out of three different cubics?

Editing Wikipedia, and wondered what word / term I should link to.

Ex: 74088 (everybody likes 42).  $42^3 = 2^3 \times 3^3 \times 7^3$

Comment: Do you require 3 prime factors, as in your example?

Comment: Seems trivial. If $~n = a \times b \times c,~$ then ...

Comment: @user2661923 Your description includes too many cubes. For example a=b=1, c=u is any cube at all, and a=6,b=5,c=7 is 210^3 , which is actually four cubes multiplied.

Comment: Yes, the term is "cube". If a number is the product of 3 distinct cubes, then it itself is a cube. Nothing special about that

Comment: "everybody likes 42" - if you mean the famous joke with $42$ , I neither find this joke good nor do I "like" $42$ (whaetever this even means). "three different cubics". You mean "product of three distinct cubes" ? I think this is already the perfect terminology , I am not aware of a further shortcut.

Comment: @H. sapiens rex The issue I have with "cube" is that to most humans it implies equal sides.  Like (2^3 * 2^3 * 2^3) = 8^3 = (2^3)^3 = 512.  I could probably see Rectangular Cuboid Cubic if it implied three distinct.

Comment: I think you're getting too caught up in the geometric interpretation of "cube"... there will be just as many people who interpret it in the algebraic sense (which is the sense I had in mind when writing)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest "cube of product of three distinct primes". Multiplication being both an associative and a commutative operation, we have for example $2^3 \times 3^3 \times 7^3=(2 \times 3 \times 7)^3$.

Since $1$ is not normally considered a prime, this formulation also avoids the issue raised in coffeemath's comment about the cube $1$ also being a factor of any cube.

Comment: Hmm, I was actually hoping for something like a "Commutative cubic" or "Associative cubic" or similar, where it implies you can move the exponentiation inside or outside and it won't matter.  That you can cube the terms, or cube their product, and its the same.